# Show ‘Out of stock’ simple products in the configurable product?

Tags: magento

Does anyone know how to list the out of stock simple products in a configurable product? For example i have an item with several attributes,size etc. If i have a certain size out of stock it will not list in the drop down, i would like it to still appear here but also telling the customer it is out of stock. Is this possible?

i have tried with many mods available in google but all fails

i am using magento 1.6

Source `http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/33550/`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it works well. I used it at v1.9, line numeration is a bit different.
Line 179 modify to

```
if(!$this->_validateAttributeValue($attributeId, $value, $options)) {
    $inStock = false;
}
```

Then after line 202 add

```
'stock' => $inStock
```

and get code

```
$info['options'][] = array(
    'id' => $value['value_index'],
    'label' => $value['label'],
    'price' => $configurablePrice,
    'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'],$value['is_percent']),
                            'products'  => $productsIndex,
                            'stock'     => $inStock
                        );
```

In `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\type\options\configurable.php`
specify after line 29

```
$inStock=false;
```

Tested on default demo template for v.1.9. It shows a simple product item in a drop down list, but selection is not available.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure, but I think that you'll achieve what you want by modifying line 151 of Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable:

```
if(!$this->_validateAttributeValue($attributeId, $value, $options)) {
   $inStock = false;
}
```

Then later, at line 170, you can include this flag in options array:

```
$info['options'][] = array(
    'id'        => $value['value_index'],
    'label'     => $value['label'],
    'price'     => $configurablePrice,
    'oldPrice'  => $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
    'products'  => $productsIndex,
    'stock'     => $inStock
);
```

then, in frontend:
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\type\options\configurable.php
you have $options var where the stock flag is stored - you can use it to create your logic
I didn't test this so make sure it works

Comment: you now have it in jsonconfig, try to see why it's not populating, in product.js ... good luck